# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException при запуске кода через FireFox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Хочу открыть сайт через `selenium`. Есть вот такой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

install_service = webdriver.ChromeService()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=install_service)
driver.get('путь к сайту')
```

При запуске из Google всё работает корректно, но когда я решил запустить на Firefox:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('путь')
```

Я получил ошибку

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

Я решил проверить запуск браузера отдельно, но всё равно получаю такую ошибку. Хотя этот пример разработчики сами приводят на своём [сайте](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/firefox/#service)

Comment: Разработчики приводят на своём сайте другой пример.

Comment: @wchistow какой?

Comment: Вы в вопросе привели ссылку, видимо, на пример, и тот пример отличается от приведённого вами в вопросе.

Comment: @wchistow нет, это, видимо, якорь на ссылке не туда ведёт, но наверху страницы есть пример. Я его копировал при попытке решить проблему